# How to pass a db_query as an array instead of a string?

Tags: entities

I am having a bit of trouble converting my module db_query argument to pass as an array as oppose to a string. The module is D6 and I am trying to port it D7. Here is the snippet:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nfi.field_name, nfi.label
  FROM {field_config_instance()} nfi
    INNER JOIN {field_config()} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name
  WHERE nfi.type_name = '%s' AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0", $type_name);
```

And here the updated version as suggested below, but I am still getting a PDOException error:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nfi.field_name, nfi.label
  FROM {field_config_instance()} nfi
    INNER JOIN {field_config()} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name
  WHERE nfi.type_name = ':type_name'  AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0", array(':type_name'=>$type_name));
```

The full error is as below, line 49 is the line starting "WHERE" or the entire bottom line basically:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() nfi INNER JOIN field_config() nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name ' at line 2: SELECT nfi.field_name, nfi.label FROM {field_config_instance()} nfi INNER JOIN {field_config()} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name WHERE nfi.type_name = ':type_name' AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0; Array ( [:type_name] => page ) in cck_private_fields_get_content_private_fields() (line 49 of C:|... common.inc).

Any suggestions welcome. When I manage to finish this module I'll be submitting it to Drupal.org so everyone can use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors in that query:

- The database tables are not field_config_instance(), and field_config(), but field_config_instance, and field_config. Parentheses have a particular meaning in SQL, and putting them after a table name causes an error message.
- The field_config_instance table doesn't contain any "label" field. See the schema definition given in [field_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.install/function/field_schema/7).

  ```
  $schema['field_config_instance'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a field instance',
      ), 
      'field_id' => array(
        'type' => 'int', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'description' => 'The identifier of the field attached by this instance',
      ), 
      'field_name' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 32, 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => '',
      ), 
      'entity_type' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 32, 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => '',
      ), 
      'bundle' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 128, 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => '',
      ), 
      'data' => array(
        'type' => 'blob', 
        'size' => 'big', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'serialize' => TRUE,
      ), 
      'deleted' => array(
        'type' => 'int', 
        'size' => 'tiny', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => 0,
      ),
    ), 
    'primary key' => array('id'), 
    'indexes' => array(
      // Used by field_delete_instance().
      'field_name_bundle' => array('field_name', 'entity_type', 'bundle'),
      // Used by field_read_instances(). 
      'deleted' => array('deleted'),
    ),
  );
  ```
- Drupal 7 placeholders aren't wrapped between quotes, when they are for strings.

The following query should not return any error.

```sql
SELECT nfi.field_name FROM {field_config_instance} nfi
  INNER JOIN {field_config} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name
  WHERE nfi.type_name = :type_name  AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Drupal 7, you should name your array items and placeholders.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nfi.field_name, nfi.label
  FROM {field_config_instance()} nfi
    INNER JOIN {field_config()} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name
  WHERE nfi.type_name = ':type_name' AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0", array(':type_name'=>$type_name));
```

In Drupal 6, `db_query()` doesn't take an array as second argument.

Comment: Thank you for your help Drupac. I am still getting a PDOException error though unfortunately. I have updated the question above to reflect the changes and the error, please have a look :)

Comment: The quotes are wrong. Use nfi.type_name = :type_name.

Comment: Hi Berdid, thanks for your input. If I take out the quotes from just the line above it still gives the same PDOException unfortunately. If I take them out of the array also i.e array(:type_name=>$type_name));  I get a fatal error on that line instead. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The documentation for [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6) clearly states that, "Instead of a variable number of query arguments, you may also pass a single array containing the query arguments." It is not true that in Drupal 6 `db_query()` doesn't take an array as second argument. Also, Drupal doesn't use parentheses after table names, such as in {field_config_instance()}; Drupal uses curly brackets.